Specialize a method template with type parameter with a non-type one
I'm trying to implement a class template with static member functions that can handle different types. My code looks like this (very simplified example):
#include <array>

struct Foo {
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr size_t foo(T v);
};

template<>
constexpr size_t Foo::foo(double v) {
    return sizeof(v);
}

template<int count>
constexpr size_t Foo::foo(const std::array<int, count>& v) {
    return sizeof(int) * v.size();
}

However, when I try to compile it, I get the following error:
<source>:16:23: error: out-of-line definition of 'foo' does not match any declaration in 'Foo'
   16 | constexpr size_t Foo::foo(const std::array<int, count>& v) {
      |                       ^~~
1 error generated.
Compiler returned: 1

How can I specialise a template with another template?

You cannot partially specialize template member function both for template type member function and non-type template function

There is no partial specialzation for function templates, but you can partially specialize a class template:
#include <array>
#include <cstddef>

template <typename T> struct Foo_impl;

template <> struct Foo_impl<double> {
    constexpr static size_t value = sizeof(double);
};

template <size_t count> struct Foo_impl<std::array<int,count>> {
    constexpr static size_t value = count * sizeof(int);
};
 
struct Foo {
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr size_t foo(T v) { 
        return Foo_impl<T>::value;
    }
};

Also note that you must use the right type, size_t not int.

I think that you missed the sizeof(int) in the second specialization.

@LoS indeed, though its not essential for the question. Thanks, fixed

foo is declared in Foo as a method template with a type parameter (typename T).
You first specialization with a double parameter is a valid specialization of that template.
But your second one isn't valid because you cannot specialize a function/method template with a type parameter (typename T) with a non-type parameter one (int count) (this kind of partial specialization is only possible for class templates).
Instead you can simply add another method template that uses a non-type parameter to Foo:
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    template<typename T>
    static constexpr size_t foo(T v) {
        return sizeof(v)+1; 
    }

    // Added: a version with non-type parameter:
    template<size_t count>
    static constexpr size_t foo(const std::array<int, count>& v) {
        return sizeof(int) * v.size();
    }
};

template<>
constexpr size_t Foo::foo(double v) {
    return sizeof(v);
}

int main()
{
    // Use the non-type parameter version:
    std::cout << Foo::foo<3>({ 1,2,3 }) << std::endl;  

    // Use the specialized type parameter version:
    std::cout << Foo::foo<double>(1.1) << std::endl;

    // Use the default type parameter version:
    std::cout << Foo::foo<int>(123) << std::endl;
}

Output:
12
8
5

Live demo
A side note: the non-type parameter count being a size of std::array should be size_t (not int).

"But your second one isn't valid because you cannot specialize a template with a type parameter (typename T) with a non-type parameter one (int count)." This is partial specialization which can only be done with class templates, but not with function templates

@463035818_is_not_an_ai I didn't get it. The first specialization is also of a function, not a class, but it is OK because it specialize the type.

see here for what I mean: https://godbolt.org/z/h7Wcjo1xj. Your statement is wrong. You can write a partial specialization that has a non type parameter for a template with a type parameter. But only class templates allow partial specialzation

@463035818_is_not_an_ai now I see. Updated accordigly.
